# Naming for Python installations in Unix and good use of the shebang

Tags: python, installation, shebang

I am confused about the standard way to write the shebang for a Python script.

I have a plain "python" link which depending on the system it could be either Python 2.x or Python 3.x and that is a problem since both are incompatible.

As a solution I write the version in my shebang and have something like:

```
#!/bin/env python3.2
```

But that seems foolish because it will prevent my script from running in any other 3.x release

I have noticed that *some* systems have python2 linked to the latest release. That helps, since that way I could write simple scripts, like "Hello World" which will not break with every release.

I have installed Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2 Using just "python" for the shebang does not make sense from a portability point of view. Using the exact version hinders maintainability. I do have a python2 link, but not not a python3

Is there any standard and/or PEP specifying how Python should be installed? And one that says that I deploy to must have a python3 and/or python2 linked to the latest release?

Answer (score 2):

Almost anything that works with Python 2.x works with Python 2.7 unchanged. The same goes with Python 3.x and Python 3.2. Anything that doesn't should be changed (no really, it should).

Then it's simply the usual naming scheme:

#### Python 2.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

#### Python 3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: +1 for using env. Thats how I write my scripts. And if you combine it with virtualenv you can keep using the same shebang with multiple environments of the same or different python versions.

Comment: Looking my computer at work and my Mac OS X Lion at home, there is no such thing as a python2 or python3 command. The Mac official installation does not have them, however the MacPorts package makes a  "python2" link, but not a "python3" one. In my Ubuntu distro I had python3.2 as default python interpreter, therefore  (#/usr/bin/env python) was indeed python3.2 and probably it will also be replaced for many users within a future. I must deploy python apps and I would like having a link to the docs/PEPs or whatever to blame the users and not me, when my software breaks :-P

Comment: Just in case there is some magic beyond hard links and the path environment when using env, I have just checked that using /usr/bin/env python3 fails although I do have 3.1 and 3.2 :(

Comment: yeap, I use virtualenv to survive the Python version hell, but still, it is not standard, so not expected to be installed in every Python installation. A simple Bourne Shell script could survie since 1977, but it seems that no Python script can survive a couple of years without updating the shebang for every single Python release :(

Comment: @nightcracker: I think you left the bang out of the shebang in your examples (as did the OP).